# How to use DBCursor provided in mongodb java driver in spring-data-mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, repository, spring-data-mongodb

I want to read around 1 million documents from my mongodb database and I am using spring data mongodb. I do not want to read all of 1 million data at once for performance reasons. Is there any way in spring-data-mongodb to do this. In raw java driver we have DBCursor.

One way i know is using pagination through repositories. Is there any other way in latest versions of spring data mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use pagination with spring data mongodb.  `MongoRepository` extends from [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) which means you can call `findAll(Pagable)` and provide page information.

Alternatively, you can use `mongoOperations/mongoTemplate` to get a `DBCollection` reference, and then call `find()` on the collection and that will return you the `DBCursor` you want.